# Decompose an ideal into sum of a product with maximal ideal and a principal ideal.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, integral-domain

> Let $A$ be a domain and $J\subset A$ be an ideal. Let $m$ be a maximal
> ideal in $A$, and $I=mJ$. Let $x\in J\setminus I$. I want to show that
> $J=xA+I$.

As pointed out by Mindlack's answer, above statement is wrong. The full setup in the book is as the following:

Let $A$ be a Dedekind domain, then an ideal $I$ admits a unique factorizaiton by primes $I=p_1^{e_1}\dots p_r^{e_r}$. Let $J=p_1^{e_1-1}\dots p_r^{e_r}$. Let $x\in J\setminus I$. I want to show that $J=xA+I$.

The statement is used to prove that $A/I\cong  (S^{-1}A)/I (S^{-1}A)$ for a multiplicative set $S$ disjoints from each $p_i$ in decomposition of $I$. So could you please not use that conclusion, to avoid circular argument?

Answer (score 2):

Edit: I'm answering the modified question, my point about the original question is below. Note that by the Chinese remainder theorem $A/I \cong \prod_i{A/p_i^{e_i}}$, so $J/I \cong p_1^{e_1-1}A/p_1^{e_1} \cong p_1^{e_1-1}A_{p_1}/p_1^{e_1}A_{p_1}$ but $A_{p_1}$ is a DVR (thus a PID) and thus the above is a one-dimensional $A/p_1$-vector space, so is generated (over $A$) by the image of *any* nonzero element, for instance the image of $x$.

---

The original question is wrong in general. Indeed, assume the result holds with $J=m$ and $A$ Noetherian. Then $m/m^2$ as a vector space over $A/m$ is generated by $[x]$ so has dimension one. As $A$ is an integral domain, $A_m$ (thus $A$) is a field or $A_m$ is a regular local ring of dimension $1$ hence a DVR.

If you want an explicit example, take $A=\mathbb{C}[X,Y]$, $m=J=(X,Y)$. Then $Y \in m \backslash (XA+m^2)$.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. I think I made a fault when trying to simplify the setup in the book. I'll try to correct it.

Comment: The question is corrected, hope you don't mind look at the new one.

Comment: I'm very sorry, but in fact my lecture notes used the statement in the question to prove that $A/I\cong  S^{-1}A/I S^{-1}A$ for a multiplicative set $S$ disjoints from $p_i$ in decomposition of $I$. I think you were using it for $p_1^{e_1-1}A/p_1^{e_1} \cong p_1^{e_1-1}A_{p_1}/p_1^{e_1}A_{p_1}$ in your answer. So to avoid circular argument, I should find an answer that not using it. Thank you again for your answer.

Comment: @scd: Can't you short-circuit it in some way? Here, we're localizing wrt a maximal ideal when quotienting by (a power of) said maximal ideal. From abstract nonsense it's enough to show that the $p_i$ are maximal ideals.